# Delphi ReportBuilder columns issue

Tags: delphi, report-builder2.0

I am working with Delphi XE6 with ReportBuilder version 15.05 build 275.

I want to print images on paper decided  by user.
Eg:

[image]

Say width of paper is 10 cm and
report column property is set to 2
So column width will be 10/2 = 5 cm each.

We leave some margin at the beginning, Draw images in first column
and then Column Width / 2 = x cm.

so we start second column from x cm + initial margin.
But it starts from x cm point only.

I want to place images in 'n' columns.
How do I draw in second column?

Comment: Replace 2 by n? Or are you asking a different question?

Comment: I gave an example of 2..It can be n

Comment: `ColumnWidth = (PaperWidth - Margin) / n`. Print column n at `Margin + (n-1) * ColumnWidth` (First column is 1 in this formula) P.S. I recommend a review of aritmetics.